# SyntaxError: ..\node_modules\react-router-native\BackButton.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (7:14):

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with react-router-native in react-native project,
Just enter code here boot with yarn start I have this error in console:

```
   5 | 
   6 | class BackButton extends React.Component {
>  7 |   handleBack = () => {
     |              ^
   8 |     if (this.history.index === 0) {
   9 |       return false; // home screen
  10 |     } else {
```

Add [`@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

I have tried to follow the suggested guide, that is to install .

> @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

To insert the file `.babelrc` and `babel.config.js` in the root, but it didn't work.

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mod/common": "1.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-art": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-multi-lang": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.16",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your babel config?

Comment: Do you have babel configured? I can't see `babel` in your package.json.

Comment: babel.config.js

module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-propterties"]
  };